# .AwaitMessage() in user DM

Tags: node.js, discord.js

I'm trying to use `.awaitMessages()` in a user DM. Unfortunately, no matter what I try, it always says `.awaitMessages()` is undefined. I need it to get message in a dm, it can't be in a channel. Is this possible?

I have already tried the following

```
let member = message.mentions.users.first();
member.user.dmChannel.awaitMessages
```

and a couple of other variations, but none of them worked. I could not find any answer online anywhere (that worked or answered the question I had).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welcome to Stack Overflow. Hopefully we can help you resolve this issue.

I notice that you're actually declaring `member` as a User. `awaitMessages` also isn't a property, but a method. Use this revised code:

```js
let user = message.mentions.users.first();
if (!user.dmChannel) return console.log('No active DM channel');

let filter = m => m.author.id === user.id;
user.dmChannel.awaitMessages(filter, { max: 1, time: 60000, errors: ['time'] })
  .then(collected => {
    ...
  })
  .catch(collected => {
    if (collected.size === 0) return console.log('Failed to send a message');
  });
```

[*Discord.js Docs*](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/general/welcome)